# How does binary file should look like?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm beginner in programming and I have a problem.
I want to write a structure to my binary file. And I'm not sure with the result. Here's the structure:

```
struct clientData
{
    unsigned int id;
    char name[25];
    char post[15];
    char degree[10];

    clientData(unsigned int, char*, char*, char*);
};
```

As you can see, my structure contains some char strings. 
Here's the main question:
**Should my strings be reconverted in final binary file (so they unreadable for applications like notepad etc)?**
Because my result looks like that (I can't add the images, so I'll just paste it):

> Miles Edgecombe МММММММММdocent ММММММММpew1 МММММММ

And this is how I write to the binary file:

```
ofstream binary_1st("binary_input.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
...
binary_1st.write((char*) &cl, sizeof(clientData));
...
binary_1st.close();
```

Comment: What format do you want in the binary file?

Comment: As a beginner, it's usually easier to stick to text format.

Comment: @MSalters Im student and my task is to use binary files for storing data, so I can't avoid it :D

Comment: If you are a student, then the rule is *make the lecturer happy*.  Go through your class notes and see if they talk about the complicated stuff in my answer below.  If any of  it is mentioned, you need to attend to it.  If not, you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing structure to the files *as-is*, without any serialization or packing. So the structure will be written as it is, strings will be readable (if they are readable in the code), numbers will be numbers, etc.

BTW, this M's in

```
Miles Edgecombe МММММММММdocent ММММММММpew1 МММММММ
```

means that character arrays in your structure are not zeroed before writing strings to them, so there are no trailing zeros at the end and thus 'thrash' will be written at the end.

Comment: The most interesting thing in my situations is that numbers are reconverted and unreadable (the first symbol with ID is unreadable and can't be pasted here)

Comment: That's because text editor tries to represent your number as ascii character (or according to the encoding set). And if this number is not a valid character code, it won't be displayed properly in text mode. However hex-editor will show you the real value.

Comment: This is why I was confused. HEX editor shows me hex-value, but strings haven't changed at all :)

Answer (score 0):

> Should my strings be reconverted in final binary file (so they
>   unreadable for applications like notepad etc)? Because my result looks
>   like that (I can't add the images, so I'll just paste it):

Don't worry about this.  Your strings probably don't contain newlines. Anyone code that converts the binary into text format should worry about Notepad &c.

**You probably shouldn't be inventing your own binary format**.  But if you really must, then watch out for the following.

- Make sure it contains version information.
- Be clear about data sizes, probably replace that `int` with something with a fixed 32- or 64- bit size.
- Store your integers byte-for-byte so that it has a fixed endiannes.  See http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons.
- Use a fixed string encoded.  UTF-8.
- Make sure you know how your strings terminate.  Either stick a size in front of them, or write out a NUL byte after the string (you example code does neither).

**update:** I just noticed my answer was probably not very clear for beginners, but I don't want to make it into an essay.  The main point is that storing the struct verbatim is probably not a good idea.  If you need more details on the rest, please ask.

Comment: I highly doubt that the OP is really going to need all of this for his simple playing around. While yes, these points are important when creating a portable binary format, it really isn't necessary if you're just persisting minor state.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII If you're just persisting minor state, a text format is more appropriate.  If you want to be able to read the data later, then you reall do have to follow Adrian's recommendations.

Comment: Correct.  Although if the OP is playing around he should probably stick to text.  It's no easier to parse than the binary, but it is more useful.